# update_post_meta() is not saving the value

Tags: post-meta

I have been working on this for hours already but cannot manage to find a solution.

I am using this code to save a value for a metabox:

```
$fecha_proxima_revision = sanitize_text_field($_POST['fecha_proxima_revision']);
var_dump(update_post_meta($post_id, 'fecha_proxima_revision', $fecha_proxima_revision));
echo 'Post ID: '.$post_id.' - Value: '.$fecha_proxima_revision;
```

The output shows that the data is actually correct:

[image]

But in the database the value will not change:

[image]

It is a very strange case because I have worked with metaboxes a million times, but today it's like that value does not want to be saved into the database.

Also if I manually run `update_post_meta($post_id, 'fecha_proxima_revision', 'whatever')` it won't be updated.

I did not do add_post_meta with unique set to true. Never. This is the only line that has ever been used with that meta key.

The context, to see where `$post_id` comes from:

```
function seguimiento_planes_guardar_metaboxes($post_id, $post){

// Pero no si es un autosave
if(defined('DOING_AUTOSAVE') && DOING_AUTOSAVE){
    return $post_id;
}

// Cancelar si el usuario no tiene permisos para editar
if(!current_user_can('edit_post', $post_id)){
    return $post_id;
}

....

}

add_action('save_post', 'seguimiento_planes_guardar_metaboxes', 1, 2);
```

What can I do to debug this issue?

Comment: Your code uses `fecha_proxima_revision` as the meta key, but the screenshot from your database shows `fecha_proxima_renovacion`. Are you *sure* you're looking for the right item when you're checking the DB?

Comment: Also, where does `$post_id` come from?

Comment: @PatJ Thanks a lot for your kind attention. Actually I am updating two meta boxes and the same is happening for both. But to try to keep it simple I just attached one of them and did it wrong. Sorry and thanks again for your help.

Comment: @JacobPeattie Thanks for your attention, I updated the question with the context in which $post_id is defined.